# Track Keywords from Google Adwords and GA and store them

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I run an adword campaign on google.

Users type in keywords and come to my landing pages via few ad's they see. Now my landing page has some 2 pages. One has informational which brings a user directly to the landing page after ad click - second is a signup form. Now I wish to capture the keywords he has typed in and then come into this form so that we know how users are reacting to our ads and what do they type to get to us.

The complex part is how can we use the GA - API to track this down. Since user will landing on /page and may signup finally from /page1 so we need to store those kewyords from his url (which is done via the Value Track codes in the url) and then store in the cookies so that when he later comes to /page1 and is signing up the same keywords can be passed and stored in the backed?

Is this possible and some can please help with this - where to look for how to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I append a code to my ad's URL in AdWords:

```
www.example.com/?code=some-unique-id
```

On the landing page I check for the query string parameter, and if found store it in a cookie.

Any subsequent pages can access the cookie, and get the code from the original landing page.

This is only ad-group level, but it's a start.